# Injecting into DELETE query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I'm a student (not hacker) and I have to inject the following query on mysql database:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE username='X'
```

where X is my injection string.

I cannot use ; since stacked queries is blocked in MySql + PHP.

After googling I figured out there is a command OUTPUT which outputs the deleted queries,
but in order to use that I have to close the previous query somehow.
I tried something like this:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE username='' and DELETE FROM users OUTPUT DELETED.*
```

but it didn't work. If it was two select queries I could've used UNION but they aren't...

Any ideas?

edit:

I would like to see the rows in the tables, I dont care to delete them or not as long as I see them.

Comment: So if "dont care to delete them or not as long as I see them", then why not just do a Select?

Comment: How? I cannot do DELETE query UNION SELECT query...

Comment: so you _do_ want to delete them? Your comment sounded like you did not care?

Comment: I do not care whether they're deleted or not in the end. All I want is to view the rows of the table...

Comment: You can not get a list of rows from mySQL if you submit a DELETE statement.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) grammar that indicates it can return a result set. Unless there is a way to submit two statements that bypasses the stacked queries restriction this doesn't seem possible. What is the reason for this requirement anyway? Simply asserting you are a student not a hacker isn't that convincing an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-select and do blind SQL injection:

```
dummy' AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo='bar') AND '1'='1
```

Here the user “dummy” will only be deleted if there exists a row in *table* with *foo* being equal to `bar`.

Comment: Interesting! Have you tested this and confirms it actually works? Usually MySQL complains about referencing the table that is the target of the `DELETE` directly in the `WHERE` and it needs to get pushed down into a derived table. Also `username IN (SELECT *)` seems odd.

Comment: I haven't got MySQL installed locally. [SQL Fiddle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sIzWr.png) gives an incorrect syntax error.

Comment: @MartinSmith Just a typo (`OUFILE` instead of `OUTFILE`). However, I suppose that such a select does not have any effects if it’s run as a sub-select.